# How can I call a PRO*C program directly from PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I couldn't find a similar question here.

I have a PRO*C program named `pro_c.pc`. How can I call and execute this in a piece of PL/SQL code?! Could someone give me a simple example?!

Comment: That's not going to be simple.  Why would you want to architect the system that way?  It is possible for PL/SQL to call out to the database host operating system via a Java stored procedure or via the `dbms_scheduler` package.  But that would be quite a few moving pieces to manage so it's not something that you'd normally design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! would it be still complicated via dbms_scheduler?! I am using Quest Code Tester to test my codes. I have been thinking of executing pro*c in Quest Code Tester

Comment: Given that there are quite a few testing frameworks out there, I would strongly suggest using one of them to test code that runs outside the database rather than having the database call out to the operating system to invoke executables just because you have an application that tests database calls.

Comment: thanks for your tips, I guess I'll use another tools to test pro*c programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link external libraries (Windows DLL or UNIX ".so" files) to Oracle and then make them callable via PLSQL. This has been around at least since Oracle 8i.

This though requires DBA privs on the server to set this up, and is probably not a recommended approach these days .... but useful for crunching huge data.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm) for more details.

Calling a actual program directly, as opposed to a library function from PLSQL would be done indirectly via DBMS_SCHEDULER as @Justin suggested as the easiest way, creating a program with the PROGRAM_TYPE as EXECUTABLE. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse003.htm#ADMIN12406) for more info.

A couple of things to note when doing this, the program will run as the (assuming UNIX) "oracle" user - bringing with it some security considerations, e.g. if the program creates a file it will be created as owned by oracle, and so might not be accessible to an "application" user. The program will run on the Oracle database server.